# Unknown column 'CA1001' in 'where clause'

Tags: java

I'm trying to fix this one for a while but can't find the or fix the code. The error triggered when I add a auto generated 'id' which is in method.

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "ichigo197328");
            int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            String value = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String sql = "UPDATE category SET category_name = ? WHERE category_id = "+ value;

            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, CategoryNameField.getText());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);           
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated Successfully ");
            DisplayTable();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly using a prepared statement, but you should be using a positional parameter in the `WHERE` clause instead of concatenation:

```
String sql = "UPDATE category SET category_name = ? WHERE category_id = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, CategoryNameField.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, value);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

The exact cause of the error has to do with your `WHERE` clause comparing the `category_id` string column against an unescaped string literal, e.g.

```
WHERE category_id = some_value      -- should be 'some_value'
```

SQL will interpret `some_value` as referring to a column, table, etc. name.  By using a prepared statement (which you alreary are doing), you let the database handle the proper escaping of the values.